Edit vs Improve this question
For each question, when I am logged in, I see the "edit" link, but when I am not logged in, I see the "improve this question" link instead. When I click on the "improve this question" link, I see a "Rev" drop down at the top, where I can see the different revisions (I am assuming that is what Rev means) of the question. However, when I click "edit" I do not see the "Rev" drop down. Is there an "improve this question" version of "edit" when you are logged in?

I thought "this must have been asked before somewhere" and I found this:
How do suggested edits work?

It does not really answer my question though.

You can see the list of revisions by clicking on the “edited April 23” (or whatever timestamp there is) link below the post. (If the link missing, there is only one revision.)
